# Pipeline empty when registering LLM model with Langchain and MLflow

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, langchain, mlflow

I was trying to register a langchain retrieverQA with MLflow, here is my code snippet for my model:

```
model_id='mistralai/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.1'

device = f'cuda:{cuda.current_device()}' if cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
print(device)

# set quantization configuration to load large model with less GPU memory
# this requires the `bitsandbytes` library
bnb_config = transformers.BitsAndBytesConfig(
    load_in_4bit=True,
    bnb_4bit_quant_type='nf4',
    bnb_4bit_use_double_quant=True,
    bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=torch.float16
)

model_config = transformers.AutoConfig.from_pretrained(
    model_id
)

# Prepare the tockenizer
tokenizer = transformers.AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(
    model_id,
)

# Load the moodel
model = transformers.AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    model_id,
    trust_remote_code=True,
    config=model_config,
    quantization_config=bnb_config,
    device_map='auto'
)

generation_config = transformers.GenerationConfig.from_pretrained(model_id)
generation_config.max_new_tokens = 1024
generation_config.temperature = 0.0001
generation_config.top_p = 0.95
generation_config.do_sample = True
generation_config.repetition_penalty = 1.15
generation_config.pad_token_id=50256

# Define pipeline
generate_text = transformers.pipeline(
    "text-generation",
    model=model,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    return_full_text=True,
    generation_config=generation_config,
)


llm = HuggingFacePipeline(pipeline=generate_text)

qa_chain = RetrievalQA.from_llm(llm, retriever=vectorstore.as_retriever(search_kwargs={"k": 5}), return_source_documents=True)
```

The retriever works perfectly:
[image]

Then I would like to register the qachain in MLflow to serve the model, here is the code:

```
mlflow.set_experiment("/main_RAG")

#RetrievalQA
#qa_chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(llm, vectorstore.as_retriever(search_kwargs={"k": 5}),return_source_documents=True)
qa_chain = RetrievalQA.from_llm(llm, retriever=vectorstore.as_retriever(search_kwargs={"k": 5}), return_source_documents=True)
#qa_chain = RetrievalQA.from_llm(llm, retriever=vectorstore.as_retriever())

# Log the retrievalQA chain
def load_retriever(persist_directory):
    vectorstore = FAISS.load_local(persist_directory, embeddings)
    return vectorstore.as_retriever()

with mlflow.start_run() as run:
    model_info = mlflow.langchain.log_model(
        qa_chain,
        artifact_path="retrieval_qa",
        loader_fn=load_retriever,
        persist_dir=persist_dir,
    )
```

The experiment was properly registered in MLflow.
Then I loaded the model to use it:

[image]

But when trying the following code  I get an error:

```
loaded_model({"query":"what is the sun"})
```

Here is the error:

```
File /databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/llms/huggingface_pipeline.py:167, in HuggingFacePipeline._call(self, prompt, stop, run_manager, **kwargs)
    160 def _call(
    161     self,
    162     prompt: str,
   (...)
    165     **kwargs: Any,
    166 ) -> str:
--> 167     response = self.pipeline(prompt)
    168     if self.pipeline.task == "text-generation":
    169         # Text generation return includes the starter text.
    170         text = response[0]["generated_text"][len(prompt) :]

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

It seems like the pipeline component was not logged by MLflow

[image]

The original qa_chain model had the pipeline:
[image]

Here is the packages version:

[image]

Hope I can get some help on this,

Best,

Ch.